# What is the origin of "hug"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, origin-unknown

Hugging is a universal form of endearment and the verb *hug* is a very common word in English, yet the origin of the word is unknown.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89167?rskey=jnGMN8&result=13&isAdvanced=true#firstMatch)* boldy says that "Appears late in 16th cent.: origin unknown." for its etymology, and adds that it shouldn't be mixed up with the word *hugge*:

> Not to be confounded with hugge *v.* to dread, shudder, shrink with fear or cold. Not connected with Swedish *huka*, Danish *sidde paa huk* to squat. In some shades of meaning it approaches German *hegen* to foster, cherish, originally to enclose or encompass with a hedge; but it is difficult to see how they can be connected.

Although, *hugge* is an older form of the verb *hug*, used in 1500s–1600s.

Per *OED*, the earliest citation of *hug* (first used as *hugge*) is from 1567:

> And hugge, and, busse, and cull, and cusse Thy darling apishe fruite. 
> <sub>1567   T. Drant tr. Horace *Arte of Poetrie* sig. Bvjv</sub>

With the form *hug*, though in past tense, it first appears in Shakespeare's *Richard III*  as "He hugd me in his armes." in 1597, per *OED*.

The noun *hug* is from the verb *hug*; and the earliest citation is from 1659 per *OED*.

*[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=hug)* also says of unknown origin for *hug* but adds some possible Germanic connections:

> 1560s, *hugge* "to embrace, clasp with the arms," of unknown origin; perhaps from Old Norse *hugga* "to comfort," from *hugr* "courage, mood," from Proto-Germanic **hugjan*, related to Old English *hycgan* "to think, consider," Gothic *hugs* "mind, soul, thought," and the proper name Hugh. Others have noted the similarity in some senses to German *hegen* "to foster, cherish," originally "to enclose with a hedge." Related: *Hugged; hugging*.

It is not usual that *OED* completely rejects any connection and doesn't provide any possible routes, especially for common words (although there are other examples). *Etymonline* adds some possible connections but it is still not certain for a very common word like *hug*. Would it be possible to find further explanation or more details about the etymology of *hug* to unravel its mysterious origin?

Comment: When was the OED page last updated?

Comment: @Laurel March of 2022.

Comment: I comment rather than answer, because sources are as available to the PO and others as they are to me, and authoritative reply is difficult. Old Norse hugga seems a frequent and reasonable online offering, and it parallels the contemporary Danish hygge (for example), which is associated with comfort and warmth. I favour this over the Old German hegge, to enclose (as with a hedge) but with no clear association of comfort.

Comment: @Anton Thank you. I believe it is acceptable to provide an answer with additional findings and offer a conjecture; or the most favored etymology, if you prefer. Moreover, _OED_ doesn't always have the full story. The users on EL&U are able to find additional sources for etymology questions; and it is possible to find details beyond _OED_ and _Etymonline_ where I've witnessed many times. I will search myself further when I have time; and I'm also trying to ask a good and informative question worthy of EL&U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Partridge, in his etymology dictionary *[Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English](https://books.google.ca/books?id=728Q-hLxaD0C&pg=PT675&dq=hug%20etymology%20hugge%20hugga&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3-anL2of6AhWN5RoKHdoEAmYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=hug%20etymology%20hugge%20hugga&f=false)* provides an additional possibility that the verb *hug* might be of echoic origin:

> **hug** (v, hence n) app comes from ON *hugga* (s *hug-*), to comfort or soothe, as a mother hugging her child: prob orig echoic from the accompanying words of comfort or sounds of lullaby.

An unexpected possible origin I've found is the monosyllabic origin of both *hug* and *huge* in Bantu and Herero, as *ku*. This origin is also mentioned for the word *eke*. Here is the relevant excerpt from the book *[A Language-study Based on Bantu: Or, An Inquiry Into the Laws of Root-Formation](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CK5AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=hug%20etymology%20hugge%20hugga&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3-anL2of6AhWN5RoKHdoEAmYQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=hug%20etymology%20hugge%20hugga&f=false)* (by F. W. Kolbe) where a vocal and semantic comparison of *hug* and *huge* is provided; and the connection to Bantu is explained:

> We may thus learn in Bantu that the original form of English *eke* is *UKU*, or more correctly *KU-KU*, a reduplication of the monosyllable *KU* (the initial *k* having fallen off), with the primary sense to run upward, to *run over*, to overflow, hence to be full, and to fill, to fill up, increase, add, supply.
>
> Closely allied to EKE (AUK) are the words HUG (O. Eng. *hoge, hugge*, Icel. *huga*, to care, think, *hugga*, to comfort, console, Swed. *hägna*, to hedge, wall in, Dan. *hygge*, to guard, A.-Sax. *hegan*, to wall in, guard, Ger. *hegen, hägen*, 0. Dan. *häge*, to fence, hug, cherish) and HUGE (O. Eng. *hogge, houge*, Dutch *hoog* = HIGH, O. Sax, *hoh*, Goth. *háus*, Swed. *hög*, Ger. *hoch*). HUG and HUGE are found close together in the dictionary as near neighbours, but as to origin and meaning they seem to be as distant from each other as the east is from the west. And yet they will probably, by means of the vowel-method (Chapter IV.), one day be recognised as offshoots of one and the same root; the only difference between them being that in HUGE the vowel *u* means up, high, whilst in HUG it has the opposite meaning, from above, from on high, downward, bowed down, hence bent, curved, *round*. The primary meaning of *huge* would seem to be to run up, to be high, whilst *hug* appears to have the radical sense of to run or go round, to enclose, embrace, to surround, as a garden with a fence, a child with the arms. Both words can easily be identified in Herero. Here we have the roots *hunga* and *honga* (nasalised forms of *huka* and *hoka*), which mean—
>
> 1. To *go up* (or before), to rise up, be high, end in a point, be
>    prominent; hence *o-honga*, high point, point, top, and *o-hunga*, isolated hill, properly prominent point; *hunga-ma* = "sich nach etwas richten," to go by a thing, keep a prominent point in view; and
> 2. To *go down*, bow, bend, curve, go or be round, go round a thing, put something round it ("umstellen "'), protect, as with a fence, cover, thatch, &c. (*hok-era*); take care of, "pflegen, verpflegen," nourish, foster, cherish (*hunga*).
>
> Now, if the above identification is true, then we are able to trace in Bantu the very first monosyllabic origin of HUGE and HUG. For in Herero the root-words *huka, hoka*, strengthened *hunga, honga*, can be proved to be modifications of *kuka*, to rise, start, travel, and *koka*, to be crooked, curved. The primitive monosyllabic root is *KU*, reduplicated *KU-KU* - *HU-KU* = *HU-NGU* = to go up (be high, foremost, prominent), and to *go down* (bow, bend, curve, put round).

---

<sub>The above finding provides a possible answer to my previous question also: 

[What is the origin of "huge"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/581709/what-is-the-origin-of-huge)</sub>